# How to loop through array to run API call each time

Tags: swift

First off, probably terrible description.
I have an array of items that I need to upload to a server. The length of the array could be 1 to who knows how many.
I have a set of API calls that needs to be run for each item in the array. I have not been able to come up with a way to call each item and have the apis calls finish as the loop doesn't wait for an API call set to finish before proceeding.
If I upload a single file using the following code, everything works fine but I need to figure out how to run these calls for multiple items.

Note: I am using the following code just for figure out how to do this and the DispatchQueue.async code is just used to simulate the API calls. Again, it works just fine but trying to look through, for example;

```
for item in items {
   ///api code below
}
```

The first item starts running but fails and I'm assuming because the loop ends before even the first API call is done.

API calls that need to run per item

```
import Foundation

let group = DispatchGroup()

// Convert audio
        let audioConversionOperation = BlockOperation()
        audioConversionOperation.addExecutionBlock {
        
          // enter the dispatch group
            group.enter()
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double.random(in: 2.0..<5.0)) {
                print("Audio conversion is completed")
                group.leave()
            }
            // we need to wait for the operation to complete
            group.wait()
        }

// Upload Audio
let audioUploadOperation = BlockOperation()
audioUploadOperation.addExecutionBlock {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double.random(in: 2.0..<5.0)) {
            print("Audio Upload is complete")
        }
    }

// Generate notification that audio is uploaded
let audioNotificationOperation = BlockOperation()
audioNotificationOperation.addExecutionBlock {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double.random(in: 2.0..<5.0)) {
        print("Transcription has started. Operation Complete")
    }
}

audioUploadOperation.addDependency(audioConversionOperation)
audioNotificationOperation.addDependency(audioUploadOperation)

let operationQueue = OperationQueue()
operationQueue.addOperation(audioUploadOperation)
operationQueue.addOperation(audioConversionOperation)
operationQueue.addOperation(audioNotificationOperation)
```

Since I can't seem to be able to do this in a loop, I'm trying to figure out how else to do this with a variable set of items. Also, I know that the API code is blocking right now but I'm just trying to figure out who to do this.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: What about the newer async/await?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I need to do these in serial, not async. So, one item at a time. The third party api is not designed for multiple concurrent uploads.

Comment: And you can use async/await for that

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I am going to try modifying the code using async/await now. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Use the following pattern for **parallel** tasks:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
for item in list {
   group.enter()
   api.call(completion: {
       group.leave()
   }) 
}
group.notify(queue: .main) {
    // all api calls completed
}
```

and use this one for handling tasks **one-by-one**

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "My serial queue")
for item in list {
    queue.async {
        // api call here
    }
}
queue.async {
    // all previous tasks completed
}
```

If you have **async tasks** and need to run them **one-by-one**, the use the following utility class:

```
final class SynchronizedActionsUtil {
    typealias Action = (_ completion: @escaping () -> Void) -> Void

    private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "SynchronizedActionsUtil")
    private let actionQueue = DispatchQueue.main
    private var actions = [Action]()

    var numberOfActions: Int { return actions.count }

    /// Schedule action
    /// - Parameter action: the asynchronous action to run
    func schedule(action: @escaping Action) {
        queue.async { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.actions.append(action)
            if self.actions.count == 1 {
                self.processNextAction()
            }
        }
    }

    private func processNextAction() {
        guard !actions.isEmpty else { return }
        let action = actions[0]
        actionQueue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0) { [queue] in
            action {
                queue.async { [weak self] in
                    guard let self = self else { return }
                    self.actions.removeFirst()
                    self.processNextAction()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @JoakimDanielson suggests in their comment, use async/await. `await` lets you wait until an async function completes its work. Consider the following code that simulates an async function that takes a variable amount of time to complete:

```
// This function triggers 10 calls to doAsyncTask() and logs the result returned to the console
@IBAction func handleButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    Task {
        for index in 1...10 {
            let result = try await doAsyncTask(index: index)
            print(result)
        }
    }
}


@discardableResult func doAsyncTask(index: Int) async throws -> String {
    //Wait 10-500 milliseconds (.01 to .5 seconds)
    let millisecond = NSEC_PER_SEC / 1000
    let duration = millisecond * UInt64.random(in: 10...500)
    try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: duration)
    return "Async job \(index) complete"
}
```

That outputs:

```
Async job 1 complete
Async job 2 complete
Async job 3 complete
Async job 4 complete
Async job 5 complete
Async job 6 complete
Async job 7 complete
Async job 8 complete
Async job 9 complete
Async job 10 complete
```