Call API for each item in array after fetching items from API
What I have now is: the page loads, the API is called and returns a list of items. When the API returns, I want to call the API for each individual item to request additional data. I'm stuck on this last part.
Here is what I have so far.
struct MainView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    let source: String
    let sourceId: String
    
    @EnvironmentObject var startupViewModel: StartupViewModel
    
    @StateObject var vm = PlaceViewModel(placeService: PlaceService())
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                            LazyHStack {
                                ForEach(Array((vm.attractions).enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { index, place in
                                    PlaceCardView(place: place)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .task {
                vm.fetchPlace(source: source, sourceId: sourceId)
            }
            .onChange(of: vm.place != nil) {
                if let placeId = vm.place?.id {
                    vm.fetchAttractions(placeId: placeId, page: 1)
                }
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(vm)
    }
}

As you can see, when the page loads I first call fetchPlace(). Then, when vm.place has changed, I call vm.fetchAttractions().
Here is how those calls are being made in my view model:
class PlaceViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    let placeService: PlaceServiceProtocol
    
    @Published var place: Place?
    @Published var attractions: [Place] = []
    
    init(placeService: PlaceServiceProtocol) {
        self.placeService = placeService
    }
    
    func fetchPlace(source: String, sourceId: String) {
        placeService.getPlace(source: source, sourceId: sourceId)
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { data in
                print("Received:")
                print(data)
        }, receiveValue: {[weak self] data in
            self?.place = data.data?.place
        }).store(in: &cancellables)
        print(cancellables)
    }
    
    func fetchAttractions(placeId: Int, page: Int, completion: ((_ response: [Place]) -> Void)? = nil) {
        placeService.getAttractions(placeId: placeId, page: page)
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { data in
                print("Received \(data)")
        }, receiveValue: {[weak self] data in
            guard let newAttractions = data.data?.attractions else {
                return
            }
            
            if (newAttractions.isEmpty) {
                self?.hasMoreAttractions = false
            }
            
            self?.attractions.append(contentsOf: newAttractions)
            
            completion?(newAttractions)
        }).store(in: &cancellables)
        print(cancellables)
    }
}

And here is my network layer (from this tutorial):
protocol PlaceServiceProtocol {
    func getPlace(source: String, sourceId: String) -> AnyPublisher<Response, Error>
    func getAttractions(placeId: Int, page: Int) -> AnyPublisher<Response, Error>
}

class PlaceService: PlaceServiceProtocol {
    let apiClient = URLSessionAPIClient<PlaceEndpoint>()
    
    func getPlace(source: String, sourceId: String) -> AnyPublisher<Response, Error> {
        return apiClient.request(.getPlace(source: source, sourceId: sourceId))
    }
    
    func getAttractions(placeId: Int, page: Int) -> AnyPublisher<Response, Error> {
        return apiClient.request(.getAttractions(placeId: placeId, page: page))
    }
}

enum PlaceEndpoint: APIEndpoint {
    case getPlace(source: String, sourceId: String)
    case getAttractions(placeId: Int, page: Int)
    
    var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .getPlace:
            return "/place/get"
        case .getAttractions:
            return "/place/attractions/get"
        }
    }
    
    var method: HTTPMethod {
        switch self {
        case .getPlace:
            return .post
        case .getAttractions:
            return .post
        }
    }
    
    var headers: [String: String]? {
        switch self {
        case .getPlace:
            return nil
        case .getAttractions:
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    var parameters: [String: Any]? {
        switch self {
        case .getPlace(let source, let sourceId):
            return ["source": source, "source_id": sourceId]
        case .getAttractions(let placeId, let page):
            return ["place_id": placeId, "page": page]
        }
    }
}

protocol APIClient {
    associatedtype EndpointType: APIEndpoint
    func request<T: Decodable>(_ endpoint: EndpointType) -> AnyPublisher<T, Error>
}

class URLSessionAPIClient<EndpointType: APIEndpoint>: APIClient {
    func request<T: Decodable>(_ endpoint: EndpointType) -> AnyPublisher<T, Error> {
        let url = URL(string: BuildConfiguration.shared.baseURL)!.appendingPathComponent(endpoint.path)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        let keychain = KeychainSwift()
        
        request.httpMethod = endpoint.method.rawValue
        
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        
        // Authorization
        request.addValue("Bearer " + (keychain.get("token") ?? ""), forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        
        do {
            // convert parameters to Data and assign dictionary to httpBody of request
            request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: endpoint.parameters ?? [], options: .prettyPrinted)
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
        endpoint.headers?.forEach { request.addValue($0.value, forHTTPHeaderField: $0.key) }
        
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
            .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))
            .tryMap { data, response -> JSONDecoder.Input in
                print(response)
                guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                      (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
                    throw APIError.invalidResponse
                }
                return data
            }
            .decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

After fetchAttractions() is called, I want to call the API again to fetch additional data for each attraction in the list.
What is the best way to do this? I've tried looping through each attraction inside fetchAttractions() however I experienced lag while scrolling.

This may help you...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77833417/how-to-loop-through-array-to-run-api-call-each-time

Note, NavigationView is deprecated use NavigationStack. Also there is no need to use
ForEach(Array((vm.attractions).enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { index, place in ...
just use ForEach(vm.attractions) { place in .... You seem to be using very old code, I suggest you try
updating to more modern concurrency framework (async-await) and @Observable class.... With async/await you can then fetch all attractions in parallel.

@workingdogsupportUkraine Is this not async network calls? https://medium.com/@islammoussa.eg/swiftui-and-combine-building-a-solid-network-layer-for-handling-api-requests-5ccce878212a

This is using the older SwiftUI and Combine from years ago, what I'm suggesting is the more modern approach
of using the more modern Swift concurrecny async/await framework.
Typically a REST call is just a oneliner, let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url). In addition to the many SO posts on the subject,
See also:
Concurrency
or Update App with Concurrency

Ah, I thought Combine WAS the newer way of doing things

Try something like this:
let place: Place
@State var details: PlaceDetail?
@Environment(\.placeController) var controller

…

.task(id: place.id) {
    details = await controller.fetchDetails(for: place)
}

